# Close Twitter follow popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am using following code to render and track Twitter follow which is working fine

```
<script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    twttr.events.bind('follow', function(event) {
        console.log('followed');
        // code to close 'follow' popup window
    });
</script>
<a href="https://twitter.com/twitter" class="twitter-follow-button">Follow @twitter</a>
```

I am looking for a way to automatically close the popup window opened after 'Follow' event is tracked. Any ideas?